# how to compare same category products in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I Have overridden the **CompareController.php** in local folder but not working then i rename both my  controller and magento's core **CompareController.php** controller but then also the addtocompare functionality is working

```
<?php

//notice that require_once is calling **CompareController.php** under the Product directory
    require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'Product'.DS.'CompareController.php');

class Company_Catalog_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController
{
public function addAction() {

    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        return;
    }

    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

    $productPresent = false;
    $found = array();
    $compareProducts = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();

    $itemCount = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount();


    if($itemCount) {
        $compareProductId = $compareProducts->getFirstItem()->getId();
        $compareProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($compareProductId);
        $compareProductCats = $compareProductCollection->getCategoryIds();

        foreach($categoryIds as $num) {
            if (in_array($num,$compareProductCats)) {
                $found[$num] = true;
            }
        }

        foreach($compareProducts as $products) {
            if($productId == $products->getId()) {
                $productPresent = true;
            }
        }

        //Check if categories of products to be compared are matching
        if(empty($found)){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError(
                $this->__('You cannot compare %s with the items in the comparison list. Please select products from the same category.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
            );
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }            

    }

    //Add product in comparison list
    if ($productId && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {

        if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The product %s has been added to the comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
            );
            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
        }

        Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
    }

    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you have? Please post  the complete error message you are getting and what you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Now it is working fine....thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can't override controller in this way. Magento class loader not looking in local folder for controller class.

But you can add call of your own contoller before controller wich action you want override
For this you need create you own module with new controller and in config.xml add this lines:

```
<config>
 ...
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyModule_Compare before="Mage_Catalog">MyModule_Compare</MyModule_Compare>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
...
</config>
```